# Including digital signature in form verification

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have developed a custom form which my customers need to sign upon receipt. The form is then converted to a PDF.
there are also a number of required fields.

Once the user clicks submit, the form checks to make sure all required fields are completed before it is submitted. I cannot, though get the signature to be checked.

I am using sketch.js to capture the signature.

form:

```
<div id="contact-form">
    <form  method="post" action="/" name="pdf-download">
        <div class="podrecieved">
            <h3>Recieved by<h3>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
            <label for="firstname">Name:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstname" name="firstname">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
            <label for="email_id">Email address:</label>
            <input type="email_id" class="form-control" id="email_id" name="email_id">
        </div>
        <div>                 
            <label for="messages">
                <span class="required">Additional Comments:</span> 
                <textarea id="messages" name="messages" placeholder="Please write your message here." tabindex="5"></textarea> 
            </label>  
        </div>   
        <div class="container">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <h3>Click to sign</h3>
                            <input type="text" id="txt" style="border-radius: 5px;">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="editor"></div>  
        <button name="submit" type="submit" id="submit">Download PDF</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

JS - Validation at top

```
jQuery(function($){

  var $form =  $("form[name='pdf-download']"),
    $successMsg = $(".alert");
    $.validator.addMethod("letters", function(value, element) {
      return this.optional(element) || value == value.match(/^[a-zA-Z\s]*$/);
    });
    $form.validate({
      rules: {
        firstname: {
          required: true,
          minlength: 3,
          letters: true
        },
        email_id: {
          required: true,
          email: true
        }
      },
      messagess: {
        firstname: "Please specify your name (only letters and spaces are allowed)",
        email_id: "Please specify a valid email address"
      },
      submitHandler: function() {
        $ = jQuery;

        $( "#submit" ).click(function() {
            alert("Submitted");
        make_product_sheet();
    });


    function make_product_sheet() {

        console.log("#submit clicked");
        var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');
        var options = {
            pagesplit: true
        };
        pdf.addHTML(document.getElementById("product_sheet"), function() {

            ps_filename = "generated-product-sheet";
            pdf.save(ps_filename+'.pdf');
        });
    }
      }
    });

});
```

I have tried adding in

```
$form.validate({
      rules: {
        firstname: {
          required: true,
          minlength: 3,
          letters: true
        },
        email_id: {
          required: true,
          email: true
        },
        txt: {
          required:true'
      },
      messagess: {
        firstname: "Please specify your name (only letters and spaces are allowed)",
        email_id: "Please specify a valid email address",
        txt: "Please add signature to form"
      },
```

Ideally I would like the form only to be allowed to be submitted once there has been a signature added att he bottom, any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a boolean and after the creation of the signature pdf (should exist a callback) change it to true. Then use an if boolean true to proceed with validation or show an error to the user asking for the signature.

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me. I have been looking through the JS and there is a number of areas that I feel I could be adding the boolean to and am unsure which one is the correct one. The code I have used has been taken and adapted from https://codepen.io/rongxike/pen/MJMopq

Comment: The '<img>' tag starts with a source - 'img64: 'data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7' ' this then gets changed when the signature gets added to the pad